# Radio buttons and hidden fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a list that appears when the radio buttons are clicked, I am having a problem with the way the list appears once the button is clicked.

Here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/c2webdev/4bpKE/

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .none {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' data-id="bank"/>Running Event
<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' data-id="school"/>Other challenges
<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' data-id="bakery"/>Baking

<div id="school" class="none">
    <label for="name">What was the activity called?</label>
    <select id="myList">
        <option value="1">List item 1</option>
        <option value="2">List item 2</option>
        <option value="3">List item 3</option>
        <option value="4">List item 4</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="bank" class="none">
    <label for="name">What was the activity called?</label>
    <select id="myList">
        <option value="1">Pancake Making</option>
        <option value="2">Egg and spoon race</option>
        <option value="3">Sack race</option>
        <option value="4">Three leg race</option>
    </select></div>
<div id="bakery" class="none">
    <label for="name">What was the activity called?</label>
    <select id="myList">
        <option value="1">Pancake Making</option>
        <option value="2">Egg and spoon race</option>
        <option value="3">Sack race</option>
        <option value="4">Three leg race</option>
    </select></div>
<script>
    $(':radio').change(function (event) {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $('#' + id).addClass('none').siblings().removeClass('none');
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help

Comment: looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rYjqY/1/

Comment: You have not enabled jQuery in the Fiddle. Other than that everything seems to be working fine.

Comment: @Pinocchio He said he needed help, but didn't bother explaining what kind of help...

Comment: @Shomz Alright, fair enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a class name `.select` to your select containers. If you added another radio in the future, this way fill it. So:

**CSS:**

```
.select {
    display: none;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function (event) {
    $(".select").hide();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $('#' + id).show();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' data-id="bank" />Running Event
<input type="radio" name='thing' value='valuable' data-id="school" />Other challenges
<div id="school" class="select">
    <label for="myList1">What was the activity called?</label>
    <select id="myList1">
        <option value="1">Virgin London Marathon</option>
        <option value="2">Round the Island cycle challenge</option>
        <option value="3">Kilimanjaro trek</option>
        <option value="4">Thames Path Challenge</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="bank" class="select">
    <label for="myList2">What was the activity called?</label>
    <select id="myList2">
        <option value="1">Pancake Making</option>
        <option value="2">Egg and spoon race</option>
        <option value="3">Sack race </option>
        <option value="4">Three leg race</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

[See Demo by jquery enabled](http://jsfiddle.net/hallaji/4bpKE/3/)

Comment: I did not. Kindly I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set a library, e.g. jQuery on the left pane